# Bootstrap: from Css to Config

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently managing a web application using Bootstrap V3 as base css framework. The CSS used is not the standard template, but some customization has been made to less variables. Unfortunately, the configuration file has been lost.
Does anybody know if there's a way to get the **config file starting from the Css**?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do yu mean go from css to less varaibles and mixins?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this.

One possible way you could regenerate most of it would be to export a default bootstrap file, then use a diffing tool to see what has changed. Then you could cross reference the changed values with the default config and manually reconstruct the config file.

Comment: **mmhh** that's exactly what i supposed in the first instance. I honestly thought there might be out there someone that experienced it in the past, and found out some tool. Anyway, shit happens. I'll have to diff a lot then ;-) Thanks for the help!